# Having trouble opening blob image from mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm kind of a noob so I don't know if I'm missing something small. The images are uploaded to the database just fine, but using this just gets me a blank square. I don't know if I'm missing something obvious?

```
$name = $_SESSION['username'];
$sql="SELECT pic FROM userinfo WHERE username = '$name'";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $pic = base64_encode($row['pic']);
        echo "<img height='300' width='300' style='padding-left:10px;' src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".$pic."'>";
    }
}
```

The upload code, I'm 95% sure that the issue is somewhere in the upload process. I commented out what I was previously using to send the query.

```
$name = $_SESSION['username'];
$bio = $_POST['bio'];
$sql="UPDATE userinfo SET pic='$pic' WHERE username='$name'";
$stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("b", $pic);
$pic = base64_encode($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
//$query = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I would hope that the image was base64 encoded before it was stored on the database. Try replacing `$pic = base64_encode($row['pic']);` with `$pic = $row['pic'];`

Comment: Would I need to change the `<code>`    src='data:image/jpeg;base64,    `</code>` part too? Sorry if this comment doesn't highlight right

Comment: Answer deleted, as there seem to be many other things you dont know how to do, that seem now to have become my problem!

Comment: Like what? What don't I know how to do?

Comment: Like all the other comments on my answer

Comment: Is this not a place for questions?

Comment: Yes, but now I am debugging the code that stores the images. That was not part of the original question. In IT speak this is called ___Scope creep___

Comment: You said you couldn't solve it because you couldn't see the uploading/storing code..

Comment: @BryanSettles I help out here between writing my own code. Debugging my own code and where I dont know something YET **reading the manual** I am not responsible for your complete site, just because I attempted to help you with a little piece of it.

Comment: Added the changed upload code, still not working but at least narrowing on problem. And Riggs, never said you were, just trying to learn